# Unknown class [A Collection View Controller] in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios5, ios6, uicollectionview

I wish to run iOS 6 programs on my iOS 5.1.1 iPad 1st generation, and all the `UICollectionView`s are all disappeared and debug console says

```
Unknown class collectionViewController in Interface Builder file
```

Is it because of incompatibility with `UICollectionView`s in iOS 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. According to the documentation for the UICollectionView class, its availability is marked as "Available in iOS 6.0 and later." which means it does not exist in iOS 5.

Comment: +1. Is there a way to get a compile-time error for this? Even with "deployment target" set to 5.1, it compiles just fine. Do I have do download the old SDK? If so, how?

Comment: For an UICollectionView compatible version with iOS5 I`m using https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView

Comment: Hello friends, is it possible to add CollectionViewController in xib not in storyboard..in ios 6 .are you having any sample or reference url for that...